# Render an image with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am storing an image in mongodb with BinData type.

I can query the database using [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) with this.

```
db.images.findOne({

                   file_name: 'temp.jpg',
                  },

              function(err, data){

                console.log(data.image); // image buffer appears on the console
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'});
                res.end(data.image);

           });
```

This produces "TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer".

I am pretty sure this has something to do with buffers or encoding.
Can some please explain what I should be doing to the image-data before sending to the browser?

Comment: Is the error being thrown on the db.images.findOne line, or in the callback function?

Comment: I think the problem is image-data inside the callback function not being the "correct" format

Comment: Can you do a "typeof data.image" in your callback? I suspect the issue is data.image being an image buffer, so it needs to be converted to something else to send back. Try converting it to base64, i.e. data.image.toString('base64')

Comment: typeof data.image is object. I no longer get there with toString("base64") but the image on the browser is corrupt. Maybe because the image is not base64 but binary type.

Comment: Try just toString() without arguments. Also, you might want to verify that the data being stored in mongo isn't being modified in some way. There's some info on how to store binary stuff in mongo here, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS. The non-optimized way to do it would also be to base64 encode the image data before storing in mongo, so it would exist as a string. This can then be read back out and converted to binary before sending to the client.

Answer (score 0):

- set the correct content type
- set the correct content length

short example how i serve my files from mongodb gridfs

```
.getFileFromGridFs(doc,function(err, buffer){
  if(err) return next(err)
  res.setHeader('content-type',doc.mimeType)
  res.setHeader('content-length',doc.size)
  buffer.pipe(res)
})
```